# Erro "Class 'MongoClient' not found"

Tags: php, mongodb

Instalei recentemente no meu Macbook o MongoDB, fiz a instalação da extensão no PHP nativo, o qual eu estou utilizando junto com o apache nativo. O problema é o seguinte, se executo a pagina Web no Apache recebo a seguinte mensagem:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/docs/www.alice.local/Branch/academia/public/index.php on line 6
```

Mas se eu execute com o comando `php public/index.php` recebo a mensagem do seguinte modo:

```
 object(MongoClient)#1 (4) {
  ["connected"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["status"]=>
  NULL
  ["server":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["persistent":protected]=>
  NULL
}
```

Arquivo PHP:

```
 <?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $c = new MongoClient();
    var_dump($c);
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer com " fiz a instalação da extensão no PHP nativo"? Também, você fez alguma alteração em algum `php.ini`?

Comment: ele criou automaticamente um arquivo chamado mongo.ini. Fiz a instalação do PHP nativo pois o Mac Os já vem com PHP e Apache nativamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Das duas uma:
Ou você tem duas versões do interpretador PHP e seu apache está configurado com um deles;

Você tem a configuração `php.ini` , `mongo.ini` disponível somente para o versão **cli** (console), o que é mais provável.

Eu não sei como é disposto os arquivos de instalação no MAC OS, mas geralmente em ambientes Linux você pode ter uma extensão que está habilitada para o cli mas não para cgi e httpd (Apache, por exemplo). Por exemplo, veja:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que sob cada SAPI (apache2, cli, cgi) há um correspondente `php.ini` e um diretório chamado de `conf.d` contento arquivos (ou link simbólicos) `.ini` que geralmente são de configuração de uma específica extensão (ex.: mongo.ini, xdebug.ini, etc). Então, o que quero dizer é:
Se você tem um arquivo de configuração que habilita uma determinada extensão somente sob uma destas interfaces (apache2, cli, cgi) ela só estará disponível quando você acessar PHP através dessa interface.

No seu caso, eu estou quase certo de que o `mongo.ini` (de acordo com seu comentário há um arquivo desse em algum local, mas você não disse) está sob algo como `php5/cli/conf.d/mongo.ini`.
Se este for o caso, apenas copie ou crie um link simbólico em algum local como `php5/apache/conf.d` (mas novamente, não estou certo de como estes arquivos são dispostos no MAC OS). Talvez até mesmo copiando o conteúdo de `mongo.ini` para o `php.ini` principal resolva.

De qualquer forma, tenha em mente que esta extensão é obsoleta.

Comment: Era realmente isso, o CLI tinha os arquivos ini em uma pasta, e o apache estava em outra. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Na documentação do [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php) existe o seguinte aviso:

> **Atenção:** A extensão que define está classe está obsoleta. Ao invés dela você deve-se usar a extensão [*MongoDB*](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php). Alternativas pra esta classe:
>
> - [MongoDB\Driver\Manager](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php).

Ou seja provavelmente você instalou a extensão do *MongoDB* pras novas funções e classes.

O uso correto seria este:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
var_dump($manager);
```

### Instalando a extensão

Adicione no php.ini isto:

```
extension=mongodb.so
```

Se for Windows:

```
extension=php_mongodb.dll
```

É necessário baixar a extensão para a mesma versão do seu php, no caso como ela requer *PHP5.4+* ou *HHVM 3.9+*, sendo PHP você pode tentar instalar via *pecl* no terminal:

```
$ sudo pecl install mongodb
```