# Como descobrir quais extensões estão instaladas no meu PHP?

Tags: php

Existe alguma maneira de se descobrir quais extensões estão instaladas no meu PHP?

Eu já sei que posso fazê-lo com `phpinfo`, mas acho confusa a visualização.

Existe uma maneira mais simples, ou seja, somente as listas das extensões instaladas?

Comment: Não entendo o motivo do downvote, acho uma pergunta valida e que pode gerar diferentes tipos de respostas +1... estou a formular uma no momento que acho que pode ser uma melhor alternativa ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento deve ser alguém que já deve saber listar os módulos do PHP e acha que é besteira compartilhar o conhecimento com os outros (irônico)

Comment: Pode ser, não posso afirmar mas pelo argumentos que já li, pois por incrível que pareça existem usuários que comentam no SOen e no "portuguese" (diferente daqui), o argumento é sempre algo como, pergunta sem pesquisa prévia. Geralmente se a pergunta é uma duvida no uso, pra eles está OK, mas se é uma pergunta que você nem sabe por onde começar mas existe documentação então "toma negativo", pelo simples fato pra eles de que você deveria ter pesquisado. Só que o engraçado é que o próprio Help incentiva a criarmos perguntas pra agregar bom conteúdo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Terminal

Fora o citado comando de terminal na outra resposta:

```
$ php -m
```

### Usando php

Ainda existe a opção de fazer em PHP, que é legal para exibir talvez em um dashboard ou se você criou um instalador do tipo wizard que verifica o que está ativo e é necessário. Existem 2 tipos de extensão, as "extensões normais" as as "extensões zend", no caso você pode usar a função [get_loaded_extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php)

```
array get_loaded_extensions ([ bool $zend_extensions = FALSE ] )
```

- Listar extensões normais:

  ```
  print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
  ```
- Listar extensões zend:

  ```
  print_r(get_loaded_extensions(true));
  ```

### Verificar funcionalidade ("Feature detecion")

Os exemplos citados anteriormente são bons para momento de instalação ou configuração, no entanto para um software de produção o recomendável é verificar se a funcionalidade é suportada com funções como:

- [`class_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php):

  ```
  bool class_exists ( string $class_name [, bool $autoload = true ] )
  ```

  Um exemplo:

  ```
  <?php
  if (class_exists('PDO', false)) {
       //Usar PDO
  } elseif (class_exists('mysqli', false)) {
       //Usar mysqli
  }
  ```
- [`function_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php):

  ```
  bool function_exists ( string $function_name )
  ```

  Outro exemplo com `function_exists` e `class_exists`:

  ```
  <?php
  if (function_exists('imagecreatetruecolor')) {
       //Usar $image = imagecreatetruecolor();
       //...
  } elseif (class_exists('Imagick', false)) {
       //Usar $image = new Imagick();
       //...
  }
  ```
- [`extension_loaded`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php):

  ```
  bool extension_loaded ( string $name )
  ```

  Também temos o `extension_loaded`, no entanto você também pode usar, um exemplo pra verificar se tem `GD` ou `Imagick`:

  ```
  <?php
  if(extension_loaded('gd')) {
      print_r(gd_info());
  } elseif (extension_loaded('imagick')) {
      $imagick = new Imagick();
      print_r($imagick->queryFormats());
  } else {
      echo 'Nenhuma extensão de imagem disponível';
      exit;
  }
  ```

  Ela não tem problema algum, o problema que ocorre é se alguma função mudar de nome, um tanto quanto raro de acontecer, mas assim você irá pegar um erro de `undefined` o que pode ocasionar uma série de problemas na sequencia já que a extensão funciona mas os nomes das funções não existem mais ou mudaram de formato (de procedural para classe por exemplo). Veja este exemplo de um possivel problema:

  - [Erro “Class 'MongoClient' not found”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/106538/3635)

Comment: Esse último exemplo já vi sendo utilizando no `Gregwar\Image`. É uma biblioteca para trabalhar com imagens. +1 pelo exemplo :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters No código fonte deles? Acredito que o ultimo seja bom, mas o `function_exists` e `class_exists` sejam melhores

Comment: Acho que me enganei. Vi isso foi no código fonte do Laravel. Lá tem um trecho que verifica se [mcrypt está ativado](https://github.com/tlgreg/laravel-framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php). Ele usa `extension_loaded`

Answer (score 3):

No terminal, dá pra usar o comando `$ php -m`

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou aqui :)